# why Line chart becomes scatter chart in python matplotlib plot?

Tags: python, charts, line

I drew a CPI chart using the data from fred.
The format of CPI data is one dot per month.
Here is the code sample.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dVOrfCN6NdM4vmjm3AO-2JZuidrvnTzG91uJE0P9ZVw/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

At the beginning（2019-2015）, the chart is line chart, but later, it becomes scatter chart. Why, and how to fix to keep the result as a line chart ?
Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# 读取CSV文件
data = pd.read_csv('normalizedData.csv')

# 将Date列转换为日期时间类型
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])

# 绘制不同曲线的叠加图片
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))

# 列名中的'Date'为时间，所以剩余列即为要绘制的曲线数据列
columns_to_plot = [col for col in data.columns if col != 'Date']

# 使用不同的颜色绘制曲线，并以第一行的列名作为标签
plt.plot(data['Date'], data['CPI'], label='CPI', marker='o', markersize=6)  

# 添加标题和标签
plt.title('Time Series Indicators')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Values')

# 添加图例
plt.legend()

# 显示图形
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Result I got
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not reproduce your figure: you may have run your code in a jupyter notebook / ipython session in which current variables have different values than what you'd expect.

I have downloaded your data, renamed columns in your script to `"DATE"` and `"RTWEXBGS"`, used the following code snippet and got a correct figure.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# 读取CSV文件
data = pd.read_csv('/Users/athual/Downloads/normalizedData.csv')

# 将Date列转换为日期时间类型
data['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(data['DATE'])

# 绘制不同曲线的叠加图片
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))

# 列名中的'Date'为时间，所以剩余列即为要绘制的曲线数据列
columns_to_plot = [col for col in data.columns if col != 'DATE']

# 使用不同的颜色绘制曲线，并以第一行的列名作为标签
plt.plot(data['DATE'], data['RTWEXBGS'], label='CPI', marker='o', markersize=6)  

# 添加标题和标签
plt.title('Time Series Indicators')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Values')

# 添加图例
plt.legend()

# 显示图形
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I realize the problem. Take CPI data as an example, it is released once a month

For example:
2023.1.1, value1
2024.2.1, value2
2024.3.1, value3

If one data point per day is the X-axis, and the Y-axis value is one data point per month, the image looks like a scatter chart, instead of a line chart
[image]
Some people will say: sampling once a month will solve the problem.

Here's the problem: When I try to overlay the dollar index, the dollar index may be published on another day of the month.

In this scenario, is there any way to get two(more) curves instead of two(more) scatter plots?

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve the scatter issue.
I tried the interpolation method with MathNet.Numerics nuget package in C#.
Here is the code

```
public class MathService : IMathService
    {
        public List<DateValue> Interpolate(List<DateValue> inputList)
        {
            List<DateValue> interpolatedList = new List<DateValue>();

            // Extract data points
            List<double> dataPoints = new List<double>();
            List<double> values = new List<double>();
            foreach (var item in inputList)
            {
                var convertable = double.TryParse(item.Value, out double value);
                if (convertable)
                {
                    dataPoints.Add(item.Date.ToOADate());
                    values.Add(Convert.ToDouble(item.Value));
                }
            }

            // Perform cubic spline interpolation
            CubicSpline spline = CubicSpline.InterpolateNatural(dataPoints, values);

            // Generate interpolated data points (every day)
            DateTime startDate = inputList[0].Date;
            DateTime endDate = inputList[inputList.Count - 1].Date;
            for (DateTime date = startDate; date <= endDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
            {
                if (inputList.Select(x => x.Date).Contains(date))
                {
                    var dateElement = inputList.Where(x => x.Date == date).FirstOrDefault();
                    interpolatedList.Add(new DateValue { Date = dateElement.Date, Value = dateElement.Value.ToString() });
                }
                else
                {
                    double interpolatedValue = spline.Interpolate(date.ToOADate());
                    interpolatedList.Add(new DateValue { Date = date, Value = interpolatedValue.ToString() });
                }
            }

            return interpolatedList;
        }
    }




[TestMethod]
        public void InterpolationHelper_Should_Work()
        {
            List<DateValue> inputList = new List<DateValue>
            {
                new DateValue { Date = new DateTime(2023, 1, 1), Value = "1" },
                new DateValue { Date = new DateTime(2023, 2, 1), Value = "0.8" },
                new DateValue { Date = new DateTime(2023, 3, 1), Value = "0.6" }
            };

            IMathService mathService = new MathService();
            List<DateValue> interpolatedList = mathService.Interpolate(inputList);

            foreach (var item in interpolatedList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{item.Date.ToShortDateString()}: {item.Value}");
            }

            var nullValueCnt = interpolatedList.Where(x => x.Value != null).Count();
            Assert.IsTrue(nullValueCnt == interpolatedList.Count);
        }
```

Here is the result picture after the interpolation.
[image]